# how to fetch data from an array of text textarea with a button using that button

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have a problem fetching text from a dynamic array of textarea-button pair. Every button in the array somehow always points to the first textarea.

this is my code snippet.

```js
//submit findings
$('#table').on('click', 'input#accept', function() {

  var id = $('textarea#<?php echo $valas->id; ?>').val();

  alert(id);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php foreach ($appointment as $item=>$valas) { ?> //...

<td colspan="4">
  <textarea id="<?php echo $valas->id; ?>" style="resize:none;" class="form-control" name="finding" cols="30" data-id="<?php echo $valas->id; ?>" rows="3">
  </textarea>
</td>
<td colspan="1">
  <input id="accept" data-id="<?php echo $valas->id; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="re-submit">
  <input id="reject" data-id="<?php echo $valas->id; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirm('are you sure you want to reject this prescription?')" value="reject">
</td>

<?php }?>
```

Sorry for bad English

**-edit by koenpeters, copied from the comments-**

Generated JS

```
$('#table').on('click', 'input#accept', function() {
    var id = $('textarea #').val();
    alert(id);
})
```

Generated HTML

```
<td colspan="4">
    <textarea id="finding" style="resize:none;" class="form-control" name="finding" cols="30" data-id="335" rows="3"></textarea>
</td>
<td colspan="1">
    <input id="accept" data-id="335" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="re-submit">
    <input id="reject" data-id="335" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirm('are you sure you want to reject this prescription?')" value="reject">
</td>
```

Comment: Could you please add the javascript and html that your PHP generated?

Comment: `'input#accept'` appear only element attached to `click` event ? Is `php` setting  duplicate `id` `#accept` to all `input` elements ?

Comment: this is the javascript 

`$('#table').on('click','input#accept', function(){

      var id = $('textarea #').val();

      alert(id);

    }) `

this is the html
`<td colspan="4">
<textarea id="finding" style="resize:none;" class="form-control" name="finding" cols="30" data-id="335" rows="3"></textarea>
</td>
<td colspan="1">
<input id="accept" data-id="335" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="re-submit">
<input id="reject" data-id="335" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirm('are you sure you want to reject this prescription?')" value="reject">
</td>`

Comment: @guest271314 no, i have set a unique id to every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your generated JS. It says `$('textarea #')`. It seems to miss the id itself.

As an alternative to what you've done: I would do this by looking for the textarea that is in the same `tr` as the buttons that was clicked. Something like this:

JS

```
$('#table').on('click', 'input#accept', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('textarea').val();
    alert(id);
})
```

demo HTML

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <textarea id="finding" style="resize:none;" class="form-control" name="finding" cols="30" data-id="335" rows="3"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <input id="accept" data-id="335" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="re-submit"/>
            <input id="reject" data-id="335" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirm('are you sure you want to reject this prescription?')" value="reject"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <textarea id="finding" style="resize:none;" class="form-control" name="finding" cols="30" data-id="335" rows="3"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <input id="accept" data-id="335" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="re-submit"/>
            <input id="reject" data-id="335" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirm('are you sure you want to reject this prescription?')" value="reject"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yxeyefx8/

Comment: I seem to have notice that also. how can i get the id of the textarea. whenever i link the id it always misses it.

Comment: Take a look at my revised answer. It shows you a way of doing this without needing the ids